# Evaluation of integral $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{(k-\frac{1}{2})^{u+j}}{(k+\frac{1}{2})^{u+j+2}} \sqrt{k} J^2_{\ell}(k) \sin{(\tau\sqrt{k})}dk$

Tags: calculus, analysis, definite-integrals, bessel-functions, laplace-method

I have an integral involves products of Bessel functions and sine function,

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\Big(k-\frac12\Big)^{u+j}}{\Big(k+\frac12\Big)^{u+j+2}}~\sqrt{k}~J^2_{\ell}(k)~\sin{\big(\tau~\sqrt{k}\big)}~dk$$

in which, $u$ and $j$ are natural numbers, $\ell$ is arbitrary integer and $\tau$ is a real number, large or small. 
$$J^2_{\ell}(k)
=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi} J_{0}(2k\sin\theta)\cos{(2\ell\theta)} \mathrm{d}\theta$$ 
And initial integral turns out to be
$$
\frac{1}{\pi}
\sum_{n=0}^{u+j}
\binom{u+j}{n}(-1)^n
\int_{0}^{\pi}
[\int_{0}^{\infty}
\frac{\sqrt{k}}{(k+\frac{1}{2})^{n+2}}
J_{0}(2k\sin\theta)
\sin{(\tau\sqrt{k})}\mathrm{d}k]
\cos{(2\ell\theta)} \mathrm{d}\theta
$$

Any help on its computation, numerically or analytically, is much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I still don't have a closed form, but a good way to compute such integral is to put $k=x^2$, then approximate $J_l^2(x^2)$ over $[0,1]$ with its Taylor series and exploit the fact that $J_l^2(x^2)$ oscillates between $0$ and $\frac{2}{\pi x^2}$ for large $x$.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio,while the difficulty is also comes from $\tau$. If $\tau$ is large, the integrand oscillates sharply.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Can this integral be transformed from real axis into complex plane?

Comment: an usual tool for computing such integrals is the Laplace (inverse) transform. For instance, in order to compute $\int_{\mathbb{R}^+}f\cdot g$ we can compute $\int_{\mathbb{R}^+}\mathcal{L}(f)\cdot\mathcal{L}^{-1}(g)$. In this case, the Laplace inverse transform of the first rational function is quite easy to compute, as well as the Laplace transform of $J_l(x)$, so, in principle, the integral without the square in $J_l^{\color{red}{2}}(k)$ should be not difficult to compute.

Comment: However, issues arise when computing the Laplace transform of $J_l^{\color{red}{2}}$, that is given by a hypergeometric function. For this reason, I suspect that the given integral is highly non-elementary.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio While I would like to give $$J^2_{n}(z)
=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi} J_{0}(2z\sin\theta)\cos{(2n\theta)} \mathrm{d}\theta$$.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio I have edited the integral and how to use Laplace transform to compute the integral with respect to k. Many thanks.